# Allow switch parameter only when another switch is present

Tags: powershell

I have a function with 2 switches, with one only being required if the other is present. Currently, if the second switch is run by itself, nothing happens, which is fine, but I think I can do better. I would like to set it up so that the second parameter can only be present if the first is also. I have tried making the first one required, which technically works, but doesn't give the result that I was expecting (ambiguous param set error).

Here is my param statement:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferMDrive')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

    [switch]$NoConfirmationPrompt,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
    [switch]$TransferMDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

I modified the param statement to look like this:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferMDrive')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups',Mandatory=$True)]
    [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
    [switch]$NoConfirmationPrompt,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
    [switch]$TransferMDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

And it will prompt me for a value for `-RemoveFromAllGroups`, however if I leave it blank, I get the following:

```
Do-Something : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'RemoveFromAllGroups'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter". 
Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
At line:27 char:1
+ Do-Something -NoConfirmationPrompt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Do-Something], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Do-Something
```

If possible I would like it to fail immediately, without prompting for a value for `-RemoveFromAllGroups` if `-NoPromptForConfirmation` is passed by itself. What could I change to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would tell you that you are working against PowerShell by avoiding having it prompt for mandatory parameters.  But PowerShell doesn't handle prompting for mandatory switch parameters very well.  Here is a way to get what you are asking for:

```
function test {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferMDrive')]
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
        [switch]$NoConfirmationPrompt,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
        [switch]$TransferMDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$NewServer
    )

    begin {
        if ($NoConfirmationPrompt -and !$RemoveFromAllGroups) {
            throw "If -NoConfirmationPrompt is specified, you must also specify -RemoveAllGroups"
        }
        "Username is $username, RemoveFromAllGroups is $RemoveFromAllGroups"
    } 
}

test -Username johndoe -OldServer foo -NewServer bar -NoConfirmationPrompt
```

But then what is the desired behavior if `-NoConfirmationPrompt` is not passed in? Is `-RemoveFromAllGroups` still required?  Perhaps not.  If you don't pass in this switch then it will use the TransferMDrive parameterset.  If PowerShell sees `-RemoveFromAllGroups` then it knows it is using the RemoveFromGroups parameterset.